# Where is IIS Out-Of-Process in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I've installed all the components of IIS 7 on a Windows Server 2008 box but I don't see IIS Out-Of-Process Pooled Applications in Component Services. How do I get it ? I have a .dll file that I want to drag it here.

I have IIS 6 locally and it has IIS Out-Of-Process Pooled Applications under Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> COM+ Applications. But the same is missing in Windows Server 2008.

Thanks,
Nandagopal

Comment: Great question for serverfault.com or superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process model in IIS was changed 7 years ago with the release of Windows Server 2003 where now it uses an Application Pool model, basically you can create as many Application Pools as needed and they no longer use COM+ infrastructure for that, instead the worker process w3wp.exe is launched and managed by WAS (Worker Process Activation Service).

If what you are looking for is to use COM+ you can just launch dcomcnfg.exe which will give you the Component Services UI where you can define your own COM+ Applications, but depending on what you are looking for that is where you would define a Server Application.

Comment: I meant "The process model in IIS was changed 7 years ago"